# HTML images for a music player

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a music player. In particular a general part for artist and albums. I have a problem. I'm trying to do something like Itunes where I have the images and then the name of the artist below on a line with 3-4 artists

Then I used a "div" but for the images, I used a table, a span (maybe not in the right way) and the normal way inserted the images. I did something like that but it works only in vertical and not in horizontal where the images and the text are out of sorts.

```
img src="images/artisti/michealbuble.jpg" style="width:150px; height:150px; margin-left: -150px;    margin-top: 8px; text-align: right; flex: 1px;" />
<p style="color: black; margin-top: 160px; flex: 1px; font-size: 90%; font: Arial, sans-serif; text-align: right"> Michael Bublé </p>
```

I'm working on HTML/CSS not JavaScript part

Comment: The entertainment industry is particularly prickly about copyright.  Be careful.

Comment: Did you talk about the images? Yes I know. This site could be open just with some specific permission so I on't have problems. Thanks Bob

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/o39sj51f/